# Adding a NULL value for a datetime entry in an SQL table through Bash

Tags: mysql, bash, insert

I am attempting to populate an SQL table through reading text files via bash to hand off to the table. I have it all working except when trying to add a null value to a datetime field.

```
mysql --host 10.100.10.19 --port 3306 -utest -ptest << EOF
INSERT INTO imaging.imagestatus (StatusDate, FileName, FolderName, Status, User, CaptureDate, Kind, Preview) VALUES ('2013-05-01T15:25:55', 'fileName1', 'folderName1', 'Status1', 'User1', 'NULL', 'kind1', 'preview1');
EOF
```

I keep getting:

```
ERROR 1292 (22007) at line 1: Incorrect datetime value: 'NULL' for column 'CaptureDate' at row 1
```

for the value labeled 'NULL' which is a data type datetime in the table. I have tried the combinations '\N', '\N', 'NULL', 'null' and ' '

I started to use a temporary date: 00-00-00 00:00:00 but I want it to match other null entry formats or just a blank space in the table. Thanks for the help!

ANSWER-- As was implemented

The value in the text file name "NULL" that is pulled in can be swapped with a variable like a=NULL to get a correct NULL value for a datetime input.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're using quotes, then you're saying that you want the date to be the string 'NULL'. Did you try just using NULL?

```
INSERT INTO imaging.imagestatus (StatusDate, FileName, FolderName, Status, User, CaptureDate, Kind, Preview) 
VALUES ('2013-05-01T15:25:55', 'fileName1', 'folderName1', 'Status1', 'User1', NULL, 'kind1', 'preview1');
```

Comment: Ah, I don't know how I didn't try that. How embarrassing. I just need to have an if statement check if the text value is the string "NULL" and if so, insert a variable a=NULL into. Thanks for the quick response and your time!